# How to get a certain word in string of getline?

Tags: c++

How can someone get only a certain word in a string of a getline method? For example:

Test.txt:

```
 hi guys
 im @@Paul \t\t [GET THIS]
```

---

```
string line;
string word;
ifstream file ("test.txt");

if (file.is_open()) {
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        if (line.find("@@Paul") != string::npos) {
            strcpy(word, line.c_str());
        }
    }
}
```

How can I code it so when I find `@@Paul` it only takes the characters (`[GET THIS]`) after the double tab (`\t\t`)?

Comment: Use a `std::istringstream` and scan that one to make your life easier.

Comment: `strcpy(word, line.c_str());` that's awkward.

Comment: strcpy with a string as dest? how many warnings does that generate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is definition of getline function: istream& getline (istream&  is, string& str, char delim);

Delim is a delimitier which stops getline from reading the stream after to the given character. so you can do something like this:

```
string trash;
string properline;

getline(file, trash, '\t');
getline(file, trash, '\t'); //second tab, still trash
getline(file, properline);
```